# Partial derivative. Equation of motion

Tags: derivatives

Would somebody,please, explain to me the following notation:
$$\sigma_{xx}+d\sigma_{xx}=\sigma_{xx}+(\partial\sigma_{xx}/\partial x)\,dx. $$

I do not understand how $d\sigma_{xx}$ transforms to partial $(\partial\sigma_{xx}/\partial x)\,dx.$

Thank you in advance.

Sergey

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I would recommend a fair bit more context. What is $\sigma?$ Of how many variables is it a function?

Comment: Sorry for being vague here. σ represents stress in the direction of x-axis. σ+dσ represents change of stress at the distance  dσ. So I suppose that there is only one variable of this function (i.e. σ(x))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\sigma_{xx}$ depends only on $x,$ then the equation $$\frac{\partial\sigma_{xx}}{\partial x}=\frac{\mathrm d\sigma_{xx}}{\mathrm dx}$$ is true, and what they've done is simply make a substitution of differentials.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir.

Comment: @SergeyDukman Glad to have been of help.